# SNMP Counter32 Data to double

Tags: c#, snmp, type-conversion

Counter32 number of incoming SNMP = 237341992;

How do I make convert in c#. Because monitoring value : 4.6 Mbit

I tried convert in c#  or translation website. But it did not :/

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure comapring like with like?   1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.2 = IF-MIB::ifInOctets.2 which has SNMP type Counter which as described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718283/definition-of-snmp-gauge32-vs-counter32 can represent a value up to 2^32

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
int i=237341992;
double d=(double)i;
```