# SNMP out or in octets (Network Traffic)

Tags: network-programming, snmp

I am writing software in C# measuring or utilizing out or in octets (bytes) via SNMP. I need to do how many bytes pass in 1000 secs?

According to my research, its value gets timed out or reset sometimes because some results give a negative value.

`.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10` for input stream in **.139**

In 1024 secs it gives result of -2,1 MBytes.

How can I get accurate measurement of traffic (in or out) ?

EDIT : This code I use for calculations. It takes value in everysec and gets result.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            SnmpObject objSnmpObject, objSnmpIfSpeed;

            objSnmpObject = (SnmpObject)objSnmpManager.Get(".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.139");
            objSnmpIfSpeed = (SnmpObject)objSnmpManager.Get(".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5.139");

            if (GetResult() == 0)
            {
                float value = Int64.Parse(objSnmpObject.Value);
                float ifSpeed = Int64.Parse(objSnmpIfSpeed.Value);

                float Bytes = (value * 8 * 100 / ifSpeed);
               // float megaBytes = Bytes / 1024;
                sum += Bytes;
                tb_calc.Text = (sum.ToString() + " Bytes");
            }
            _gv_timeSec++;
            lb_timer.Text = _gv_timeSec.ToString();

            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10` is the OID for `IF-MIB::ifInOctets` which is [described](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=true&objectInput=ifInOctets) by MIB as a **Counter32** which has a upper limit of 2^32-1 (4294967295 decimal).

> "The total number of octets received on the interface,
>   including framing characters.
>
> Discontinuities in the value of this counter can occur at
>   re-initialization of the management system, and at other times as
>   indicated by the value of ifCounterDiscontinuityTime."

Quoting [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6913877/449347) :

> a Counter32 has no defined initial value, so a single reading of
>   Counter32 has no information content. This is why you have to take two
>   (or more) readings to make sense of it. An example of this would be
>   the number of packets received on an ethernet interface. If you take a
>   reading and get back 4 million packets, you haven't learned anything:
>   the wire could have been pulled out of the interface for the past
>   year, or it could be passing millions of packets per second. You have
>   to take multiple readings to know anything.

Comment: Reviewing the new code is perhaps a different question & answer that the original; it probably would be cleaner in its own new question (with input and actual/expected results).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [ifHCInOctets](http://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6) `.1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6` and [ifHCOutOctets](http://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.10) `.1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.10` which are 64 bit versions of OIDs mentioned by @k1eran

Those counters don't rotate so quickly when dealing with higher speeds.