# NetApp SNMP monitoring

Tags: snmp, netapp

I'm writing a script to pull data from a NetApp filter, I'm trying to get networking data but looking at the MIB file I can see metrics like `ifHighOutDiscards`, `ifLowOutDiscards` and `if64OutOctets`.

What do these numbers mean? Do I need to convert them to something?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? They are defined in detail in their MIB, e.g.  http://protocolsoftware.com/documents/mibs/netapp.mib.txt states ... if64OutOctets                   OBJECT-TYPE
 SYNTAX                          Counter64
        MAX-ACCESS                      read-only
        STATUS                          current DESCRIPTION  "The total number of octets transmitted out of the
                      interface, including framing characters.
                      This object returns all of the 64 bit unsigned integer."

Comment: Hello k1eran, the problem was that I was totally blind to how this works. Doing a bit of research with a person that manages the devices i'm working with i've learned that the data shown is actually the transmitted count since the device has been up and running.

Comment: This answer has a summary for SNMP Counter usage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718283/definition-of-snmp-gauge32-vs-counter32/6913877#6913877