# How do I convert gauge32 to integer?

Tags: snmp

Can anyone help me in this? I am trying to monitor the humidity for my network device and I did the snmpwalk which is:
**snmpget -v2c -cpublic -mALL 172.x.x.x .1.3.6.1.4.1.13742.4.2.x.x.x.x**
and it stated:
**SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.13742.4.2.4.1.x.x = Gauge32: 2147483647**
So what does the gauge32 means? And is there any way I can convert it to integer?

Comment: Gauge32 is an unsigned 32 bit integer internally. What is the problem you are facing? The conversion to integer is almost automatic.

Comment: Thank you for your response Sir. I edited my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definition of SNMP Gauge32 vs Counter32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718283/definition-of-snmp-gauge32-vs-counter32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIB object that you are trying to poll is defined in **PDU-MIB** from **raritan** [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AELW.png)]

```
RelativeHumidity   ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION
           DISPLAY-HINT "d"
                   STATUS      current
                   DESCRIPTION
                       "Data type for reporting sensor readings and thresholds
                       associated with humidity sensors. Relative humidity is
                       expressed as percentage and is defined as the ratio of the
                       partial pressure of water vapor in a gaseous mixture of
                       air and water vapor to the saturated vapor pressure of water
                       at a given temperature."
                   SYNTAX Unsigned32 (0..100)

humidity                OBJECT-TYPE
                        SYNTAX        RelativeHumidity
                        MAX-ACCESS    read-only
                        STATUS        current
                        DESCRIPTION
                            "The value of the external humidity sensor reported
                            as relative humidity (a percentage)."
                        ::= { humiditySensorEntry 3 }
```

So your relative humidity should be in range **[0..100].** There could be two problems:

1. The NET-SNMP fails to display the value properly for some reason
2. The SNMP Agent does not implement this object or humidity sensor is not installed or disabled on device

[image: The PDU-MIB snapshot compiled using NetDecision MIB Manager]